# systemctl status?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, services, mongodb

I'm trying to install Mongodb. It seems to install fine, but starting the process gives me errors.
**Edit: I have tried the daemon-reload.**

```
Failed to issue method call: Unit mongod.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status mongod.service' for details.
```

My services look as such:

```
root@graylog:/var/cache/apt/archives# systemctl status 
-.mount -> '/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/_2d_2emount'
-.mount - /
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab)
   Active: active (mounted) since Wed 2018-08-01 17:17:54 UTC; 1h 48min ago
    Where: /
     What: /dev/dm-0

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
boot.mount -> '/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/boot_2emount'

boot.mount - /boot
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab)
   Active: active (mounted) since Wed 2018-08-01 17:17:54 UTC; 1h 48min ago
    Where: /boot
     What: /dev/sda1

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
run-lock.mount -> '/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/run_2dlock_2emount'

run-lock.mount - /run/lock
   Loaded: loaded (/proc/self/mountinfo)
   Active: active (mounted) since Wed 2018-08-01 17:17:54 UTC; 1h 48min ago
    Where: /run/lock
     What: none

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
run-shm.mount -> '/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/run_2dshm_2emount'

run-shm.mount - /run/shm
   Loaded: loaded (/proc/self/mountinfo)
   Active: active (mounted) since Wed 2018-08-01 17:17:54 UTC; 1h 48min ago
    Where: /run/shm
     What: none

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
run-user.mount -> '/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/run_2duser_2emount'

run-user.mount - /run/user
   Loaded: loaded (/proc/self/mountinfo)
   Active: active (mounted) since Wed 2018-08-01 17:17:54 UTC; 1h 48min ago
    Where: /run/user
     What: none

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount -> '/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/sys_2dfs_2dfuse_2dconnections_2emount'

sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount - /sys/fs/fuse/connections
   Loaded: loaded (/proc/self/mountinfo)
   Active: active (mounted) since Wed 2018-08-01 17:17:54 UTC; 1h 48min ago
    Where: /sys/fs/fuse/connections
     What: none

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
sys-kernel-debug.mount -> '/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/sys_2dkernel_2ddebug_2emount'

sys-kernel-debug.mount - /sys/kernel/debug
   Loaded: loaded (/proc/self/mountinfo)
   Active: active (mounted) since Wed 2018-08-01 17:17:54 UTC; 1h 48min ago
    Where: /sys/kernel/debug
     What: none

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
dbus.service -> '/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/dbus_2eservice'

dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus (deputy systemd dummy)
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/upstart/dbus.service; static)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2018-08-01 17:17:54 UTC; 1h 48min ago
 Main PID: 19471 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: name=dsystemd:/system/dbus.service

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-acdeac7d\x2de4a4\x2d4987\x2d85b9\x2d45d3142c9e81.service -> '/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/systemd_2dfsck_40dev_2ddisk_2dby_5cx2duuid_2dacdeac7d_5cx2de4a4_5cx2d4987_5cx2d85b9_5cx2d45d3142c9e81_2eservice'

systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-acdeac7d\x2de4a4\x2d4987\x2d85b9\x2d45d3142c9e81.service - File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/acdeac7d-e4a4-4987-85b9-45d3142c9e81
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/upstart/systemd-fsck@.service; static)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-fsck@.service(8)
```

I'm trying to install and configure Graylog so I'm seeing this error a lot. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -l lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service`

Comment: I don't see a mongodb.service in this output? That would be a "problem"

Comment: Please update the output with `systemctl status mongodb` instead of all the other services.

Comment: Please also add to the question your version of Ubuntu and whether MongoDB was installed from official repositories.